# Most minimal OS that has a GUI

Tags: raspbian, gui, operating-systems, raspberry-pi-os

My ideal OS would include only a python IDE (and python of course), and have a GUI (with a file explorer and all).

I'm totally new with raspberries, and so far I've found that the most minimal OS is the lite OS that unfortunately doesn't have a GUI, making too hard to work with for me. The other OS's are full with useless programs for my case and I'd like to avoid them.

What would be the closest OS build to the one that I described in the beginning?
Thanks

Comment: This is subjective.  As you are new to the Pi, I would go with the Raspberry Pi OS with desktop rather than building one up from Lite - just use the main menu editor and untick everything you do not want to see.  Of the top of my head - there is an option to uninstall these programs as well - Linux does not suffer Windows (and Mac) issues of leaving bits behind half as much. The amount of space they take up is minimal and updates are only a few minutes.  It also simplify on-going community support as you have a standard system and not stuck trying to explain what you have done :-)

Comment: @Andrew yes, that troubled me as well, thanks for the suggestion, I will try to remove everything else through the terminal and if that's still not enough I'll end up building a GUI on top of lite

Comment: Do not forget to add file manager / browser to your build if you go that way - both are handy when developing :-). You may loose things such as auto-mount of USB drives, WiFi / Bluetooth config etc as they are add-ons.

Comment: There was no reason to close this. “Minimal” can be quantified. My “opinions” were relative to the OP’s stated and observed requirements.

Comment: @mreff555 "Minimal" is a theoretical concept which cannot be reached in practice. Which practical systems are small enough to be called "minimal" is a matter of opinion. E.g. for someone used to Windows 10, even the full Pi OS is minimal.

Comment: The OP asked for a window manager. While the concept of Minimal is infinite, the size of a window manager can be quantified in sloc's or instructions.

Comment: In some sense, I feel your question has more to do with ***hardware*** than software/OS. And since no one else has mentioned it, perhaps you should look at [MicroPython](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=micropython&ia=web). It won't work on the "mainstream" RPi hardware (2,3,4, etc) - only on [pico](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-pico/), and numerous other *microcontrollers* not manufactured by RPi.

Comment: @mreff555 "Minimal" was qualified: "only a python IDE and a GUI file browser".   The problem is following this up can only lead to ridiculousness, expressions of profound naivete, and flat out misinformation. Linux distros, with a few specialized exceptions we need not be concerned with, are all essentially the same in this context.  **They all offer the same range of software.  If you want to remove things, you can.  If you want to use foo instead of bar, you can.**  If you want a "lighter" system, you can make it ligher.

Comment: Mario, the best starting point for you is the lite version of RpiOS and then *add the GUI software you want*.  It is not a separate OS from the desktop version.  They are the same only configured differently, and all that can be changed. I am sorry but it is very unlikely you are going to get this question to fit here. If you want to pursue  this this way, it would be much better on reddit or somewhere that allows free discussion. https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/

Comment: @goldilocks thanks for the reply, and i apologize for the question on your forum, however I would like to ask: if I remove all other programs from the desktop version will i end up with a setup that would be the same as adding the essential programs to the lite OS?

Comment: I suppose if you wanted to make it exactly the same and you used an actual lite image as a reference, yes you could do that.  Of course it would be a bit pointless, but I presume you are asking to confirm that they are in fact the same OS created from the same package repo.   Starting with the GUI and then removing/replacing what you don't want *may* be slightly easier, depending on what you are trying to achieve and how familiar you are with things.  You might learn more doing it the other way though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always install the minimal installation and then install a GUI. Tiling window managers tend to be the smallest.  DWM is only 2000 sloc's and very fast.  They are also ideal for minimalist developers, but there is a learning curve and Some GUI software will require configuration to work right.  If you don't want to deal with this learning curve, look into installing openbox.  As far as I know it is no longer being developed, but it is still commonly used, even in commercial applications, as it is very complete for a bare bones window manager.  LXDE is built off of it and while it does carry some bloat, It's still quite fast.

Also, keep in mind that if you are writing software on your RPI, but are working on a headless project, it really doesn't matter.  Just shut down the GUI when performance testing your product.

Comment: thanks for everything, you really gave me good suggestions on what to do!

Comment: *"DWM is only 2000 sloc's"* -> This is exactly the kind of ridiculouslness I was referring to.   LOC tells you absolutely nothing about the performance characteristics of a piece of software, including how fast it is or how much memory it takes.  It would be easy to write a slow, bloated window manager in 2000 loc.  LOC is a perhaps useful metric for estimating how hard a project would be to maintain or develop, but it is totally irrelevant in this question.

Comment: The bulk of your answer is then about your appreciation of tiling WMs.  That's great, but it only demonstrates how easily this becomes subjective: Because there is nothing much objective or meaningful to discuss.  Again, reddit, discussion forums, wax lyrical as you want.  But not here.

Comment: Both of your comments are incorrect and not useful.  A low SLOC count in a lower level language equates to less instructions, equating to less memory utilization and better performance. I used two sentences to explain what a TWM was.  I was not trying to promote them.  I contrasted as well and gave a well rounded answer.  Which by the way, was well received.  See the check mark?   Take your trolling elsewhere.